# Storing entities from a Symfony2 Form doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1

i have a crazy problem, which i dont understand.

My code where is concerned looks like that:

```
 public function appendAction(Request $request, $pKpPatientid)
{
    if (!$this->isAdmin()) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }
    $entity = new DataDFu1();
    $entity1 = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('DataLiveBundle:DataAPatient')
        ->find($pKpPatientid);

   $appendForm = $this->createAppendForm($pKpPatientid,$entity, $entity1);


    $appendForm->handleRequest($request);
   // if ($appendForm->isValid()) {
        if($appendForm->get('submit')->isClicked()){//Save
           //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dataapatient_sendMessage', array("pKpPatientid" => $pKpPatientid)));
           $entity->setFu1KfPatientid($entity1);
           $this->storeAppendDataDFu1($entity);

     //   }
    }

    return $this->render('DataLiveBundle:DataDFu1:form.html.twig', array(
       // 'entity'     => $entity,
        'form'   => $appendForm->createView(),
        'isNew'=> true,
    ));
}

/**
 * The function createAppendForm
 * Creates a form with the Information from a DataAPatient.
 * @param DataAPatient $pKpPatientid The primary key
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form
 */
private function createAppendForm($pKpPatientid, $entity, $entity1)
{   

    $form = $this->createForm($this->get('data_livebundle.form.dataapatienttype'), $entity1, array(
    //'action' => $this->generateUrl('dataHome'),
    'method' => 'POST'
   ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Fu1'));
    return $form->add('dFu1', new DataDFu1Type(), array('data'=>$entity));

}

 /**
 * The function storeEditedDataDFu1
 * Persists changes made to an existing DataDFu1 entity to the database
 * @param  DataDFu1 entity
 * @return DataAPatient $pKpPatientid The primary key
 */
public function storeAppendDataDFu1($entity)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find DataDFu1 entity.');
    }

    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
    $session->getFlashBag()->add(
            'notice',
            'Your changes to the DataDFu1 of ID: "'."xyz". '" was saved!'
    );
   // return $entity->getPKpPatientid();
}
```

I create a form which inludes two forms with entities and render it. It works fines. But in this moment when in want store (storeAppendDataDFu1) the data from the entity and just **from this entity** the entity1 loses all values that were previously visualized in the form(just the visualized). This means that the fields displayed by this entity1 are stored persistently with the value NULL in the database.

How can entity1 persistently store the wrong values even though only one memory function has been programmed for the entity1 ()???

My presumption says that it has to do with the constellation of form, because whenever I press Submit, the fields of entity1 are set to NULL.

I hope somebody know this problem:), i really can not find a solution.
*the entity and entity1 are just connected together, because the foreig key from entity is entity1's primary key its an oneToOne matching...

i found also the mappingBy null? what means that? could it be the reason?

```
 oneToOne:
    fu1KfPatientid:
        targetEntity: DataAPatient
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: dFu1
        joinColumns:
            _FU1_kf_PatientID:
                referencedColumnName: __P_kp_PatientID
        orphanRemoval: false
```

thanks for a feedback... tell me if you need more information..Thaanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i found the issue! The Problem is that i'm using 
[Data-Toggle](https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo)

```
{#<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-left">
         <li class="active"><a href="#patientInfo" data-toggle="tab">Patient info</a></li>
         <li ><a href="#partI" data-toggle="tab">Part I</a></li>
         <li ><a href="#partII" data-toggle="tab">Part II</a></li>
         <li ><a href="#partIII" data-toggle="tab">Part III</a></li>
    </ul>
    {#div class="clearfix">tmp. disable#}</div> #}
```

to create a Register Layout. I think this kind of Layout doesn't works fine with Simfony2 Forms. Has somebody experiance which kind of Register Layout works with Symfony2 Forms?

Answer (score 0):

If the entities are related is not better to add the proper mapping information to persist both entities?

> Entity 1

```
/**
*@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity2", cascade={"persist"})
*
*/
$entity_two_reference;
```

in the form this would be a Entity2Type and should render as usual

when you make the flush() it should work fine.

Comment: Hmm..the reason why i have planed to do it with two different entities is because the first entitiy should not be changed..but when i want follow your approach where i have to define the proper information?  Does ist works with two diffrent formtypes? because now i have for every entity an own formtype

Comment: I suppose you already have the mapping information so you should not change anything in the first entity or any other entity. You only change the form of the mandatory entity and modify the field's as EntityTwoFormType and it will render and persist without any additional code.
Could you show me your entities so I can explain my self better?

Comment: Thanks for the Feedback, which files do you want see entity class, or entity forms? or both?